# combine tables with 1 to N relationship into 1 line of record with the last value of the N record

Tags: mysql, sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I need a modification of my previous post regarding 
how to combine tables with 1 to many relationship into 1 line of record

[how to combine tables with 1 to many relationship into 1 line of record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749492/how-to-combine-tables-with-1-to-many-relationship-into-1-line-of-record)

now my problem is my record has now 1 to many relationship. What I need to show is the last record only and combine it in a single line
tables tbl_equipment and tbl_warranty

[image]

and here is the desired output
[image]

here is the code I'm trying to implement

```
 SELECT
 a.equipmentid,
 a.codename,
 a.name,
 a.labelid,
 a.ACQUISITIONDATE,
 a.description,
 a.partofid,
 w1.warrantyid as serviceidwarranty,
 w1.startdate,
 w1.enddate,
 w2.warrantyid as productidwarranty,
 w2.startdate,
 w2.enddate,
 s.equipstatusid,
 l.equiplocationid FROM TBL_EQUIPMENTMST a
 left JOIN tbl_equipwarranty w1
 ON w1.equipmentid=a.equipmentid and w1.serviceproduct = 'service'
 left JOIN tbl_equipwarranty w2
 ON w2.equipmentid=a.equipmentid and w2.serviceproduct = 'product'
 left join tbl_equipstatus s
 on a.equipmentid = s.equipmentid
 left join tbl_equiplocation l
 on a.equipmentid = l.equipmentid  WHERE a.equipmentid = '112'
```

I only want to show 1 record with the last value of warranty product and warranty service in the output. Can anyone guide me how to modify my code so that when I try join all the tables listed above can produce 1 record only with the last record of warranty as an output.
I am using firebird as a database. If you have a solution in mysql kindly tell me and ill try to find the counterpart in firebird.

Comment: You can join with a subquery that uses one of the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: Are you sure you want a 1 line result. The query for A 2 (or n) line result is much more flexible/scalable

Comment: @barmar your suggestion rocks. it gave me an idea what to research on solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading the comment of Barmar at the question for solution. I Figured out subquery can solve my problem. Subquery is a new word for me. I research on how to use subquery and came out with a solution below. you can correct me if my code is wrong or how to improve the performance of the query

```
SELECT 
    a.equipmentid,a.codename,a.name,a.labelid,a.ACQUISITIONDATE,a.description,a.partofid,
    w1.warrantyid as serviceidwarranty,w1.startdate,w1.enddate,
    w2.warrantyid as productidwarranty,w2.startdate,w2.enddate,
    s.equipstatusid,
    l.equiplocationid 
FROM 
    TBL_EQUIPMENTMST a
left JOIN
    (select first 1 *
     from tbl_equipwarranty 
     where equipmentid='112' and serviceproduct = 'service'
     order by warrantyid desc) w1 ON w1.equipmentid = a.equipmentid 
                                     and w1.serviceproduct = 'service'
left JOIN
    (select first 1 *
     from tbl_equipwarranty 
     where equipmentid = '112' and serviceproduct = 'product'
     order by warrantyid desc) w2 ON w2.equipmentid = a.equipmentid 
                                     and w2.serviceproduct = 'product'
left join
    (select first 1 *
     from tbl_equipstatus 
     where equipmentid = '112'
     order by equipstatusid desc) s on a.equipmentid = s.equipmentid
left join
    (select first 1 *
     from tbl_equiplocation 
     where equipmentid = '112'
     order by equiplocationid desc) l on a.equipmentid = l.equipmentid  
WHERE 
     a.equipmentid = '112'
```

Comment: Can anyone know how to join all of them without especific equipmentid?

Answer (score 0):

```
with summary as(
select e.equipmentid ,e.Codename,e.Name,w.warrantyid ,w.Satartdate ,w.Enddate,w.warrantytype 
from Eqp e
join Warranty w
on(w.equipmentid =e.equipmentid )
where w.warrantyid =3)

select *,w.warrantyid,w.Satartdate ,w.Enddate,w.warrantytype
from summary s
join  Warranty w
on s.Satartdate =w.Satartdate and s.Enddate =w.Enddate 
where w.warrantyid =4
```

Comment: i hope this will help you to get only what you expecting in output.